# Limit of increasing function is its infimum

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

I proved that if $\mathit\\f$ is an increasing function in ($\mathit\\a,b$) then $\lim \limits_{x \to \mathit\\a+}f(x)$ exist and equals to $\inf\{f(x) | a \lt x \lt b\}$.

But is it also true that if $\mathit\\f$ is increasing in [$\mathit\\a,b$) then $\lim \limits_{x \to \mathit\\a+}f(x)$ = $\inf\{f(x) | a \le x \lt b\}$?

Comment: You could define $f(a)$ to be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x\in(0,1) \\
-10 & x=0
\end{cases} $$
Then, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$.

Furthermore, $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x)|a<x<b\}$ is true if we allow $\inf\{f(x)|a<x<b\}$ to be $-\infty$. If we don't allow this, then the assertion is true provided that $f(x)$ is bounded below.

Comment: Thanks, still got two more questions about your example: 1. How do you know that its limits at 0+ is 0? 2. inf of f in this case is -10, right? Because, look what I wrote - I said that a<=x<b

Comment: @AviAsks My example shows that the second thing you asked about is not true. You need the infimum with strict bounds: $a<x<b$ - to be true. The limit is $0$ because $g(x)=x$ is a continuous function. And yes the infimum is $-10$ for my example since it's the minimal element of the set.

Comment: I have yet to learn continuity, so I can't figure it out by myself. Though trying to prove that using the definition of limit.